# jsreport html-to-excel options

Tags: export-to-excel, asp.net-core-1.0, jsreport

I'm using the excellent jsreport solution to convert html to excel using the 'html-to-excel' recipe.
Does this recipe have any options to control the worksheet options?
Like display the sheet right to left, set the sheet's name, display grid lines etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `html-to-excel` recipe uses [html-to-xlsx](https://github.com/pofider/html-to-xlsx/blob/master/test/test.js) under the hood. According to the [document](https://github.com/pofider/html-to-xlsx#supported-properties), if you want to display grid lines, you could use css style to control grid line :

```
    td {
        border-style: solid;
    }
```

you could also use `text-align` too. But only a little features are supported.

2. The default `html-to-xlsx` (`legacy`) doesn't support custom sheet names. However, if you look into the [unit test](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-html-to-xlsx/blob/master/test/htmlToXlsxTest.js#L119,L125), you will find that there's a better `html-to-better-xlsx`:

```
      template: {
        content: `
        <table name="Data">
          <tr>
              <td data-cell-type="number">1</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        `,
        recipe: 'html-to-better-xlsx',
        engine: 'none',
        baseXlsxTemplate: {
          content: xlsxTemplateBuf.toString('base64')
        },
        htmlToXlsx: {
          insertToXlsxTemplate: true
        }
      }
```

that means adding a `[name]` attribute to `table` and setting the recipe as `html-to-better-xlsx` should work.

3. The [`Xlsx` recipe](https://jsreport.net/learn/xlsx) allows us to control over the Excel completely. For example, to custom the sheet name, see https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/BJa5OBWD-2

```
{{#xlsxMerge "xl/workbook.xml" "workbook.sheets[0].sheet[0]"}}
   <sheet name="My Sheet Name"/>
{{/xlsxMerge}}

{{{xlsxPrint}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment itminus. But I bumped into two difficulties: couldn't find the html-to-better-xlsx recipe, and I also didn't find any capability to change the worksheet's direction to rtl. In addition, I would like to avoid the xlsx recpie atm, if I can find a solution to the two problems I mentioned above.

Comment: what @itminus says is right, there is some work being done recently in the html-to-xlsx recipe that adds more features like adding names to sheets, border colors, font-family, etc however this is still work in progress, and with that i mean that you should don't rely on the new recipe being named "html-to-better-xlsx", because it is a name just used in development along with "html-to-xlsx", we were using two recipe just to be able to test differences quickly in development, the plan is that the new implementation will be just "html-to-xlsx" like always.

Comment: @ashilon about the sheet name that is supported in version under development, about show gridlines and change the worksheet's direction to rtl, i would like that you open an issue here https://github.com/pofider/html-to-xlsx and show an excel file with all of these features, so i can check how it can be done. thanks!

Comment: @BJR Matos thanks a lot, that clears things up. I will try to open an issue on github.